# I'm trying to show the current image in the pictureBox and stretch it but it's not showing anything why?

Tags: c#, winforms

In For1 i have this code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {     
                this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pictureBox1.Load(file_array_satellite[file_indxs_satellite]);
                file_indxs_satellite = file_indxs_satellite - 1;
                if (file_indxs_satellite < 0)
                {
                    file_indxs_satellite = file_array_satellite.Length - 1;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void satellitesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            file_array_satellite = Directory.GetFiles(UrlsPath, "RainImage*.*");
            if (file_array_satellite.Length > 0)
            {
                DateTime[] creationTimes8 = new DateTime[file_array_satellite.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < file_array_satellite.Length; i++)
                    creationTimes8[i] = new FileInfo(file_array_satellite[i]).CreationTime;
                Array.Sort(creationTimes8, file_array_satellite);
                file_indxs_satellite = 0;
                file_indxs_satellite = file_array_satellite.Length - 1;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new Size(500, 500);
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(this.Bounds.Width / 2,
                            this.Bounds.Height / 2);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox1.BringToFront();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                this.pictureBox1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(12,
                                27);

        }
```

In the original the picturebox1 size is 100x100 and each image i stretch to fit in the pictureBox.
When it's 100x100 everything is ok i see the animation of each image in the pictureBox.

Now i did an event that when i enter with the mouse to the pictureBox area it should move to the center of the form resize to 500x500 stretch the images and show the same animation.
And when i leave the pictureBox area it should return to it's original size and location.

When i enter with the mouse to the pictureBox1 area the pictureBox just vanish i don't see it anywhere once i leave the pictureBox area i see it 100x100 in it's original place and size.

Why when i enter with the mouse to the pictureBox1 area it's vanish i don't see it in the center of the form on size 500x500 ?

file_array_satellite is string[] and file_indxs_satellite is int.

RainImage*.* are the files names on the hard disk after downloaded them.

The idea is not to convert/change the files sizes on the hard disk each time i enter or leave so i wanted that once i enter the pictureBox1 area it will stretch the current image in the pictureBox and show it . It's working when it's 100x100 but not on 500x500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mouse over the PictureBox and move it to the center of the form, you are moving it out from under the mouse cursor.  This causes the MouseLeave event to immediately trigger, which places it back under your mouse cursor again, which causes the MouseEnter event to trigger again, etc.

You can do something like this:

```
    bool suppressMouseLeave;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        suppressMouseLeave = true;
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(this.Bounds.Width / 2,
                        this.Bounds.Height / 2);
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.BringToFront();
        //point the cursor to the new Position so that it's still kept on the pictureBox1
        //This is important because it makes your idea acceptable.
        //Otherwise you have to move your mouse onto your pictureBox and leave the 
        //mouse from it then to restore the pictureBox
        Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(new Point(pictureBox1.Left + 250, pictureBox1.Top + 250));
        suppressMouseLeave = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(suppressMouseLeave) return;
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(12, 27);
    }
```

Comment: Golden Dragon you are right with the idea if i marked now removed the mouse leave event then it's working i see it in the center of the form but then it will never back to the original place and size. Can you show me then how to do the leave event code ?

Comment: One way you could go about it would be something like this: Create a new bool in your form and set it to false.  In the MouseEnter function, if the pictureBox width is not 500, resize the pictureBox as you are doing now.  If it IS 500, set the new bool to true.  Then in the MouseLeave function, only execute the code in there if the bool is true

Comment: @DoronMuzar you may have to use 2 pictureBoxes, the first is fixed, the other is used to enlarge the image and show it at the center.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture a guess that `this.Bounds.Width` and `this.Bounds.Height` are not what you expect them to be, so the PictureBox isn't vanishing, you are just setting it to some location that is offscreen/off your form.  Run Visual Studio in Debug mode and put a breakpoint around that line and see what `this.Bounds` is equal to.  This may give you a clue as to the proper location you need to set.

Answer (score 0):

How about in "in place" zoom like this?

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rc = pictureBox1.Bounds;
        rc.Inflate(200, 200);
        pictureBox1.Bounds = rc;
        pictureBox1.BringToFront();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rc = pictureBox1.Bounds;
        rc.Inflate(-200, -200);
        pictureBox1.Bounds = rc;
    }
```